# Are the following four sentences the same in meaning?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

1. Neither you nor he is right.
2. Not either you or he is right.
3. Either you or he is not right.
4. Both you and he are not right.

Comment: You left out: 5. One of you is not right.

Comment: 2 is not grammatical. 3 means that one of you is right and the other is not. 1 and 4 mean that both of you are not right.

Answer (score 2):

- Examples 1, 3, and 4 are grammatical; example 2 is not. ("Not either" = "Neither")
- Examples 1 and 4 both mean the same thing, i.e., that both individuals are wrong (although some may argue that the two statements have differing connotations or emphases).
- Example 3 does not mean the same thing as 1 and 4, but instead posits that only one person is wrong instead of both.

Comment: The fact that (1) and (4) mean the same thing is another example of DeMorgan's Law: `Not (A Or B)` is equivalent to `(Not A) And (Not B)`.

Comment: I am confused by the following opinion. https://able2know.org/topic/550219-1#post-7038813  In 1, 2, and 4 both people are wrong. But in 3, one person is wrong. RobJavis says that example 2 is not grammatical, but Hightor says 2 is correct. In this case, what shall I do as a non-native speaker? Will you make it clearer?